# How to add "selected" to Select control option on option selection

Tags: javascript, html-select, wordpress-gutenberg, setattribute

I have a function which pulls the headers from a page and adds them as options to a HTML `select` component. I'm having trouble, however, getting the selected item to be the selected option that shows in the selector. How can I programmatically add a "selected" attribute to the option which is selected?

```
<SelectControl
   label="Select heading for jump link"
   value={jumpLink}
   id="selectheader"
   options={[jumpLink]}
   onChange={setJumpLink}
/>


let jumpLinkArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-heading')].map(item => 
item.innerText);
    const select = document.getElementById('selectheader');
    if (select && select.innerHTML) {
        select.innerHTML = '';
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < jumpLinkArray.length; i++) {
       let opt = jumpLinkArray[i];
       let el = document.createElement('option');
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
```

Comment: How do you determine which one should be selected? What is the criteria?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - that's part of the issue with the Gutenberg Block SelectControl component (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/select-control/), I'm trying to figure out, is how I can apply the "selected" attribute on a the option I've selected.

Comment: "on the option I've selected" How did you select it?

Comment: The `SelectControl` component in WordPress Gutenberg renders a normal `<select>` control, and is the correct way to use a `select` control within Gutenberg. I did notice that I can get the value of the selected option in the console with: 

`select.addEventListener('change', e => {console.log(e.target.options.selectedIndex);});`, but can't figure out how to set the `selected` attribute to the selected option.

Comment: In your `for` loop. `opt` is a string from the prevous `map()` correct. In the `map()`, try printing `item.selected` to see if you can get it directly as you loop over the items.

Comment: For some clarification, what elements are you selecting with `'.wp-block-heading'`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - `.wp-block-heading` are `h1` elements with that class. They may, however, not always be `h1`'s.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I'm able to get the boolean value of selected of each of the options on change, but not sure how I can apply the selected attribute to the appropriate option when selected based on that:

`const select = document.getElementById('selectheader');

select.addEventListener('change', e => {console.log([...e.target.options].map(option => (option.selected === true ? option.selected : false)));});`

Comment: When does the code you posted in your question execute? Are you dynamically creating this `<select>` when the page loads? And when you select an option from the SelectControl, do you want it to automatically select an option in this new dynamic <select>? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: I don't think you have answered my original question. Let me ask it another way. What are the exact interactions you want to happen here. How do you determine which option should be selected? Explain this in words.

Answer (score 0):

It was a question of how you set the selected state of the selected option so that it is set as the one in view in the component. The trick was to move the `setTimeout` up.

```
setTimeout(() => {
            let headingArray = [
                ...document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-heading")
            ].map(item => item.innerText);
            const select = document.getElementById("selectheader");
            if (select && select.innerHTML) {
                select.innerHTML = "";
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < headingArray.length; i++) {
                let opt = headingArray[i];
                let el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.selected = opt === jumpLink;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
        }, 1000);
```